# Loading data, data to array, array to JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

```
public static void load() {
    try {
        URL load = new URL("http://www.site.net/loader.php?username=" + "username" + "&password=" + "password");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(load.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    if(inputLine.length() > 0){
                        put = inputLine;
                        put.split(":");
                        System.out.print(put);

                    }
                }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you see there, I'm trying to split the following data:

[image]

How do I remove the quotations and store it in an array, so I can load it up in an JList?

Put = String put;

Comment: What is `put` ? Go from there.

Comment: Ok, what does `put.split(":");` return?

Comment: It's not working, apparantly.

Comment: Oh, it's working, you just aren't using it correctly. What do you think it does? And check what it really does (look at javadoc).

Comment: It's generally a good idea to read [the documentation of the methods you want to use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes, it is; I did, but couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String `split` method returns a String array. It does not change the original string, so this line does nothing:

```
put.split(":");
```

Instead, consider something like this. First split at the colon:

```
String[] parts = put.split(":");
```

Then for each part, remove the quotations:

```
for( int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    parts[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
}
```

Then use the array of cleaned up strings to back a JList:

```
JList myList = new JList(parts);
```

Comment: Thank you, extremely helpful. How abouts would I place parts, into a new JPanel?